# String to XML conversion after that parsing in android

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I am doing a `HttpPost` request as a return I am getting a XML I can make Toast of it I is in a String Code looks like this

```
try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xx.xx.xx.xx/login.asmx/login");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"responseBody:   "+responseBody,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

and the XML looks like

`<root status="Y">`

`<mb mbcode="150201" mbname="AKASH KUNDU" branchid="1" pwd="admin"/>`

`</root>`

I want to Parse this XML and store this data as a global variable.I  Did not found any reverent example that is why I am posing I am new here Advance thanks.

Comment: I have done it by my self code follows

Comment: You could have posted it as a answer and accepted it..

Comment: Done thanks @RahulMatte Please up-vote if you like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I found my solution**

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xx.xx.xx.xx/login.asmx/login");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());


        //saving the file as a xml
        FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("loginData.xml",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        osw.write(responseBody);
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();

        //reading the file as xml
        FileInputStream fIn = openFileInput("loginData.xml");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
        char[] inputBuffer = new char[responseBody.length()];
        isr.read(inputBuffer);
        String readString = new String(inputBuffer);



        //getting the xml Value as per child node form the saved xml
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        //InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseBody.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(readString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        Document doc = db.parse(is);

        /*DocumentBuilder builder=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc=builder.parse(fIn, null);*/
        NodeList root=doc.getElementsByTagName("root");




        for (int i=0;i<root.getLength();i++) {
            loginStatus = "" + ((Element)root.item(i)).getAttribute("status");
        }


            if(loginStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
            {
                NodeList mb=doc.getElementsByTagName("mb");
                for (int i=0;i<mb.getLength();i++) {
                    setMbcode("" + ((Element)mb.item(i)).getAttribute("mbcode"));
                    setMbname("" + ((Element)mb.item(i)).getAttribute("mbname"));
                    branchid  = "" + ((Element)mb.item(i)).getAttribute("branchid");
                    pwd       = "" + ((Element)mb.item(i)).getAttribute("pwd");

                }
```

Comment: Done, generally this happens when OP didn't got answer so he himself answer and accept. [through](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Try the Android developer guides, or http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html. It's also not too difficult to use [google](https://www.google.com).

Comment: this should be comment its contain only link.

Comment: Thanks for your response.I had tried developer.android but look at my XMl and I told clearly it I am getting the XML as String I need to convert it to XML (or any other process)so that I can parse and extract the data.And my XML format is little bid different  please see that.

Comment: I understand that, but I don't get your problem? Did you follow the links? This one for example: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html

Comment: Yes I have tried as I told there XML format and mine was little bid different.And they handling raw xml but I am getting String.inside that string I have that xml `String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());`

Comment: they are using XML format but I need to convert that String to XML then I can parse that

Comment: Maybe you want to rephrase your question such that it becomes more explicit how your setting looks like.

Comment: I said it clearly I am send a request to server and server returning a XML format.I am getting this and storing this in a string.Now I need to convert that string to XML and extract that data which are in that XML

Comment: The link http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html shows clearly how this works. I'm sorry, but I cannot do more for you.