# XML parsing on android

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

I have a XML it Looks like

`<root status="Y">`

`<mb mbcode="150201" mbname="AKASH KUNDU" branchid="1" pwd="admin"/>`

`</root>`

I want to parse it and get all the data individually,I saw many example but not a single XML looks like this all looks like

`<md>`

`<mbcode>150201</mbcode>`

`<mbname>AKASH KUNDU</mbname>`

`</md>`

I know how to parse this kind of XML please tell me how to do those kind of XML parsing

**I have done so far**

```
 DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseBody.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        Document doc = db.parse(is);

        NodeList words=doc.getElementsByTagName("root");

        for (int i=0;i<words.getLength();i++) {
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext()," " + ((Element)words.item(i)).getAttribute("value"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

**Found my solution**

```
       //getting the xml Value as per child node form the saved xml
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(readString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        Document doc = db.parse(is);

        NodeList root=doc.getElementsByTagName("root");

        for (int i=0;i<root.getLength();i++) {
            loginStatus = "" + ((Element)root.item(i)).getAttribute("status");
        }


            if(loginStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
            {
                NodeList mb=doc.getElementsByTagName("mb");
                for (int i=0;i<mb.getLength();i++) {
                    setMbcode("" + ((Element)mb.item(i)).getAttribute("mbcode"));
                    setMbname("" + ((Element)mb.item(i)).getAttribute("mbname"));
                    branchid  = "" + ((Element)mb.item(i)).getAttribute("branchid");
                    pwd       = "" + ((Element)mb.item(i)).getAttribute("pwd");

            }
```

Comment: You're just getting the "root" element.  You need to get the "md" elements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [String to XML conversion after that parsing in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14672070/string-to-xml-conversion-after-that-parsing-in-android)